# Cannot get JSON response from API

Tags: api, knockout.js, jsonresponse

I have a RESTful API web service. I'm programming a simple pure Javascript client app to interact with the APIs. I also use **Knockout** framework. My Javscript code:

```
self.movies = ko.observableArray();

 $.get(self.moviessURI, function(data){
     var obj = JSON.parse(data);
     for (var i=0; i < obj.movies.length; i++) {
       self.movies.push(obj.movies[i]);
     }
 }, "json");
```

My HTML code:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr><td><b>Title</b></td><td><b>VideoID</b></td></tr>
    <!-- ko foreach: movies -->
    <tr>
        <td><p><b data-bind="text: title"></b></p></td><td><p data-bind="text: videoId"></p></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
</table>
```

After running, I have a request status 200 on the web service, but my client app does not display anything. I also used Postman to test the API and its working.

Where did I do wrong? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update Knockout.js Observable from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967976/update-knockout-js-observable-from-json)

Comment: `ko.applyBindings(vm)` is this missing? Knockout applies bindings only if this is found.

Comment: Any errors in console? Otherwise it's probably what samuellawrentz said

Comment: I have this line `ko.applyBindings(new MovieViewModel(), $('#main')[0])` but I also really don't know what it means samuellawrentez